# Word Hangingman C# Using Only Loops

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-for-loop

I'm trying to make a hangman word-guessing game. I have come this far. The only problem now is that I would like to insert a statement of "There is no {0} in the word", playerGuess when the user inputs the wrong letter. Also, a statement that said "Yes! There is {0} in the word", playerGuess when the user enters the correct letter. I also attached a picture of how I would like the program to execute. TYVM!

[image]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Hangman!!!!!!!!!!");
            string[] listwords = new string[10] 
            {"sheep", "goat","computer","america","watermelon","icecream",
            "jasmine","pineapple","orange","mango"};

            Random randGen = new Random();
            //Get random number
            var idx = randGen.Next(0, 9);
            //Us the random number as index 
            string mysteryWord = listwords[idx];
            //Create an array to store user's guesses
            char[] guess = new char[mysteryWord.Length]; 
            //Make chosen word as asterisks
            for (int p = 0; p < mysteryWord.Length; p++)
            {
                guess[p] = '*';
                Console.Write(guess[p]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            //Loop iterates to check user input char against the chosen word
            while (true)
            {
                //Ask user for input
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your guess: ");
                char playerGuess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int j = 0; j < mysteryWord.Length; ++j)
                {
                    //What will happen when input is matched
                    if (playerGuess == mysteryWord[j])
                    {
                        guess[j] = playerGuess;
                    }
                }
                
                for(int j=0;j<mysteryWord.Length; ++j)
                {
                    //What will happen when the input is not matched
                    if (playerGuess != mysteryWord[j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is no {0} in the word", playerGuess);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Console.Write(guess);
                Console.WriteLine();

                //Print the word and end the game
                string guessString = new string(guess);
                if (guessString == mysteryWord)
                {
                    Console.Write("You win! The word is {0}", guessString);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    return;
                }
                         
            }
        }
```

```
                    /*//What will happen when the input is not matched
                      //Putting this if statement within the for block cause the program to 
                      //not do anything else after one match guess. And if the playerGuess has more     than one match in the word, the loop ignore it. I think it has something to do with the break statement.

                    if (playerGuess != mysteryWord[j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is no {0} in the word", playerGuess);
                        break;
                    }
                    */
```

Add another for loop for another if condition

```
                for (int j = 0; j < mysteryWord.Length; ++j)
                {
                    //What will happen when the input is not matched
                    if (playerGuess != mysteryWord[j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is no {0} in the word", playerGuess);
                        break;
                    }
                }
/*This code got me the closest to what I want. However, the statement still display even when a match is found. I assumed that because it inside the loop, and there will always be playerGuess != mysteryWord[j]*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a loop limitation even when iterating over strings? Because to check if a string contains a letter you can simply use the `Contains()` function like this:

```
if (mysteryWord.Contains(playerGuess))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes! There is {0} in the word", playerGuess);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("There is no {0} in the word", playerGuess);
}
```